# d3js: display tips coorectly after zoom

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to write an example using D3.js where images lay on a static background. I can move the background and zoom and I can also move separate images (something like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) but with images). Also, I need to display a tooltip when the mouse is over an image.

Here what I have tried with d3js v4:

Problems:

1. When zooming the tooltip is displayed at an incorrect location (The problem is obviously in `handleMouseOver` where `d.x,d.y` is just the initial position of the image, but I don't know how to get translate and scale parameters of the current view)
2. Width of tip is not resized automatically to the text width (should I change `div.tooltip` somehow?).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
 
 div.tooltip {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   width: 120px;
   height: 28px;
   padding: 2px;
   font: 12px sans-serif;
   background: lightsteelblue;
   border: 0px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   pointer-events: none;
 }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
 
 IS_DRAGGING = false
 
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
   .style("background-color", "#E59400") // orange
      .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
              svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }))
      .append("g");
 
 function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
 }
  
 var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);
 
 function handleMouseOver(d, i) { 
  if(!IS_DRAGGING) {
   div.transition()
   .duration(100)
   .style("opacity", .9);

   div.html(d.url)
   .style("left", (d.x+32) + "px")
   .style("top",  (d.y-28) + "px");
  }
 }

 function handleMouseOut(d, i) {
  div.transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("opacity", 0);
 }
 
 function drag_strart(d) {
   d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
   
   div.transition()
      .duration(100)
      .style("opacity", 0);
 }

 function dragging(d) {
   d3.select(this).select("image")
  .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
  .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
   
   IS_DRAGGING = true
 }

 function drag_end(d) {
   d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
   
   IS_DRAGGING = false
 }
 
 var arr = JSON.parse(data);
 arr.forEach(function(d) {
   d.x = getRandom(0, document.body.clientWidth);
   d.y = getRandom(0, document.body.clientHeight);
 })
   
 var group = svg.selectAll('g')
 .data(arr)
 .enter().append("g").call(d3.drag()
  .on("start", drag_strart)
  .on("drag", dragging)
  .on("end", drag_end))
 .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
 .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut)
 
 group.append("image")
 .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.img_path; })
 .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("width", 32)
    .attr("height", 32)
 
  </script>
</body>
```

Also, I have tried `d3js v3` and the `d3-tip` library:

They work, but have some side effects:

1. For some reason, I can't move images separately.
2. When I zoom I want the tooltip to disappear (now it just stays at the same location and is even not redrawn at a new position and at the scale of the image)
3. Sometimes something like 'blinking' of the tooltip is happening (looks like it turns on and switch off many times when the cursor is near the edge of the image).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="d3.tip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
 
 div.tooltip {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   width: 120px;
   height: 28px;
   padding: 2px;
   font: 12px sans-serif;
   background: lightsteelblue;
   border: 0px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   pointer-events: none;
 }

 .d3-tip {
   line-height: 1.5;
   font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
   padding: 10px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 3px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:101;
 }

 /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
 .d3-tip:after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display: inline;
   font-size: 20px;
   width: 100%;
   line-height: .5;
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   content: "\25BC";
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
 }

 /* Style northward tooltips differently */
 .d3-tip.n:after {
   margin: -1px 0 0 0;
   top: 100%;
   left: 0;
 }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
 
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
   .style("background-color", "#E59400") // orange
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
     svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
      }))
      .append("g");
 
 function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
 }
 
 function dragging_start(d) {
   d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
 }

 function dragging(d) {
   d3.select(this).select("image")
  .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
  .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
 }

 function dragging_end(d) {
   d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
 }
  
 var arr = JSON.parse(data);
 arr.forEach(function(d) {
   d.x = getRandom(0, document.body.clientWidth);
   d.y = getRandom(0, document.body.clientHeight);
 })
 
 var tip = d3.tip()
   .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
 .offset([-10, 0])
 .html(function(d) { return d.url; });
 
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("dragstart", dragging_start)
  .on("drag", dragging)
  .on("dragend", dragging_end);
 
 var group = svg.selectAll('g')
 .data(arr)
 .enter().append("g").call(drag)
 .on('mouseover', tip.show)
 .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
 
 group.append("image")
 .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.img_path; })
 .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("width", 32)
    .attr("height", 32)
 .call(tip);
 
  </script>
</body>
```

**Update:**

I figured out that adding `d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();` were crucial, now I can move images separately. But the problem that looks like mouse cursor is moving faster than the image itself and also I subtracted half of image w,h (in my case 32/2) to drag the image at the center (by default it was the upper left corner).

```
function dragging_start(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragging(d) {
  d3.select(this).select("image")
    .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x-16)
    .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y-16);
}
```